# Javascript. Is there a way to check inside an event handler which element sent the event?

Tags: javascript, events, aframe

I'm working with a big framework, which is entity component based. So I can't change the code of the element sending the event at all, I can only work with the receiving element.

this.id does not work, because the component ( so the event handler) is attached to a parent element of the element sending the event.

I'm working with javascript, no jquery.

I wondered if there was a way to find out inside the event handler of the receiving element: **which element originally sent the event?**

I tried browsing other solutions like

```
function doWithThisElement(event) {
event = event || window.event; // IE
var target = event.target || event.srcElement; // IE

var id = target.id;
//...
```

}

but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: I'm looking at the answers you got, but somehow I get the feeling that event.target is precisely not what you're looking for. I'm unsure what you mean by "element sending the event" though. If the user clicks a button, what is the sending element in that case, with the button being the receiving one?

Comment: to be specific I'm working with aframe and when an animation ends it emits the event "animationend". when this happens I want my event handler to work, but only for specific animations with a certain class. That's why I need to check which animation emitted the event. Does that make it clearer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `event.target`  property to know which Element triggered the event. It contains a reference to the object that dispatched the event.

Also, note that this (`event.target`) can be different from the element on which the event was registered in case of Capturing and bubble phase of events.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    var eventTarget = e.target;
    console.log(eventTarget);
    });
```

Comment: perfet this works like a charme. Thank you for the quick help, exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `event.target` property in order to returns the DOM element that triggered and initiated the event.

```js
$('div').click(function(event){
    console.log(event.target.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">div1</div>
<div id="div2">div2</div>
<div id="div3">div3</div>
```